using a "lookup" dataframe to map value pairings in R
I have a dataframe df of patient visits structured in the following format:



ID
visit_number
variable
value




34
1
height
short


34
1
weight
over


34
1
eye_color
brown


34
1
hair_color
brown


89
1
weight
normal


89
1
height
short


89
2
height
short


89
2
weight
over



df <- data.frame(ID = c(34, 34, 34, 34, 89, 89, 89, 89), visit_number = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), variable = c("height", "weight", "eye_color", "hair_color", "weight", "height", "height", "weight"), value = c("short", "over", "brown", "brown", "normal", "short", "short", "over"))

So for visit #1, patient 34 had their height, weight, eye, and hair color taken down. Patient 89 had two visits recording their height and weight.
I have a mapping file that shows a pairing of variables and values that results in a new value that I would like to pull for each relevant pairing:



var_1
val_1
var_2
val_2
new_var_name
new_val




height
short
weight
normal
health
average


height
short
weight
over
health
warn


eye_color
brown
hair_color
brown
complexion
monochrome


eye_color
blue
hair_color
blonde
complexion
contrast



mapping <- data.frame( var_1= c("height", "height", "eye_color", "eye_color"), val_1 = c("short", "short", "brown", "blue"), var_2 = c("weight", "weight", "hair_color", "hair_color"), val_2 = c("normal", "over", "brown", "blonde"), new_var_name = c("health", "health", "complexion", "complexion"), new_val = c("average", "warn", "monochrome", "contrast"))

So this mapping file shows that if a patient's height is short and their weight is normal, I would like to create a health variable set to "average". If their height is short and their weight is over, I would like this health indicator to be "warn", and so on as the other pairings in the subsequent rows show.
What would be the best way to go about doing this? We can assume that all pairings will be covered in the mapping dataframe and we can also assume that there will not be incomplete pairings in the data.

This is a sort of brute force method that might run into trouble if you have more than dozens of variables, but I expect should work fine in many situations.
First, I expand the data so every row is matched with every other row in the same patient's visit. That could get big if there are many variables. Then those pairings are matched with the mapping table, where only the labeled pairings are output.
This could be made twice as memory-efficient if we could ensure that the mapping variables were always sorted alphabetically, with var_1 < var_2. Then we could limit the first join to those pairings where variable.x < variable.y, resulting in half as many combinations to look up for the 2nd join.
library(dplyr)
df |>
  inner_join(df, join_by(ID, visit_number), relationship = "many-to-many") |>
  inner_join(mapping, join_by(variable.x == `var_1`, value.x == `val_1`,
                             variable.y == `var_2`, value.y == `val_2`)) 

Result
  ID visit_number variable.x value.x variable.y value.y new_var_name    new_val
1 34            1     height   short     weight    over       health       warn
2 34            1  eye_color   brown hair_color   brown   complexion monochrome
3 89            1     height   short     weight  normal       health    average
4 89            2     height   short     weight    over       health       warn


Thank you very much, @Jon Spring. I managed to write a bit of code to ensure that var_1 is always earlier in the alphabet than var_2 in my mapping dataframe, but I'm not sure how this changes the code. Could you kindly advise? Thanks again for your help.

You could replace the first join with inner_join(df, join_by(ID, visit_number), variable.x < variable.y, relationship = "many-to-many"), which will make the first table ~half as big, so it takes up less memory and completes the next step faster. But that adjustment might only make a difference if the data is pretty large.
